# Controle de validação ErrorMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte *model:*

```
public class Request : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Centro de Responsabilidade é obrigatório!")]
    public string Cadastro_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Cadastro Cadastro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A requisição é obrigatória!")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public bool DN { get; set; }

    public string Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Sessao { get; set; }

    object IEntity.Id
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

Todos os campos automaticamente carregados ao entrar na página são obrigatórios. Nesse formulário existe um checkbox (DN) que se marcado, torna obrigatório o preenchimento da Matricula e da Sessão. Caso DN não seja marcado, esses dois campos nem aparecem e não são de preenchimento obrigatório (uso em script pra ocultar os campos).

Segue minha view:

```
<table>       
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.DropDownList("Cadastro_Id", string.Empty)</td>
         <td>@Html.DropDownList("Nome", string.Empty)</td>
     </tr>
</table>

<br />
<div id="dn">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.DN) <b> NACIONAL </b>
</div> 

<div><br /></div>

<div class="ocultar">
  <b> Número de Matrícula </b> 
</div>
<div class="ocultar">
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Matricula)
</div>
    <div class="ocultar">
  <b> Sessão </b> 
</div>
<div class="ocultar">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Sessao)
</div>
```

Como fazer para que caso o checkbox esteja marcado os campos sejam obrigatórios e quando não esteja marcado os campos continuam ocultos e sem validação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementando a interface [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class Request : IEntity, IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Centro de Responsabilidade é obrigatório!")]
    public string Cadastro_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Cadastro Cadastro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A requisição é obrigatória!")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public bool DN { get; set; }

    public string Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Sessao { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (DN) {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Matricula)) {
                yield return new ValidationResult("A Matrícula é obrigatória!", new List<string> { "Matricula" } ); 
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sessao)) {
                yield return new ValidationResult("A Sessão é obrigatória!", new List<string> { "Sessao" } ); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Desculpa @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Não entendi muito bem. Os campos que só precisam ser obrigatórios se DN for marcado é sessão e matricula. Vou editar a pergunta com a classe do meu model inteiro pois acredito que não posso muda-la para IValidatableObject

Comment: Por que não pode?

Comment: Ah sim... Deu certo @Cigano. Perfeito!